# how to deal with strings on a numeric column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataset and I cannot convert the dtype from object to int because of the error *"invalid literal for int() with base 10:"* I did some research and it is because there are some strings within the column.

How can I find those strings and replace them with numeric values?

Comment: Can you show an example of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 'col' the column name.

Just force convert to numeric, or NaN upon error:

```
df['col_num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
```

If needed you can check which original values gave NaNs using:

```
df.loc[df['col'].notna()&df['col_num'].isna(), 'col']
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [`.str.isnumeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html), which will only allow you to filter the data for these numbers-in-strings and act on them independently .. but you'll need to decide what those values should be

- converted (maybe they're money and you want to truncate `€`, or another date format that's not a UNIX epoch, or any number of possibilities..)
- dropped (just throw them away)
- something else

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["1", "2", "x"]})
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  x
>>> df[df["a"].str.isnumeric()]
   a
0  1
1  2
>>> df[~df["a"].str.isnumeric()]
   a
2  x
```

Answer (score 2):

Base 10 means it is a float. so In python you would do

```
int(float(____))
```

Since you used int(), I'm guessing you needed an integer value.